# Define, compile and execute a terminal command in Makefile in C

Tags: c, makefile, config

during some tasks, I need to run a terminal command in a .c file. I had the following layout in my .c file and it runs perfectly fine:

```
 #ifdef CONDITION_A
 static const char * funcA(){
   #define SIZE 56
   #define T_A_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Memory Size:\""
   ...
   ...}
 #endif 

 #ifdef CONDITION_B
 static const char * funcB(){
   #define SIZE 56
   #define T_B_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Battery Level:\""
   ...
   ...}
 #endif
```

Now let's say we have `submakeA.mk` and `submakeB.mk` and the main Makefile. When you compile with `make TARGET=submakeA` the `funA()` will be compiled and run. If you run `make TARGET=submakeB`, the `funcB()` will be compiled and run.

Now I am asked to define "T_A_CMD" and "T_B_CMD" in their corresponding submakeA.mk and submakeB.mk file.

I have the following layout: 
1) In the main Makefile:

```
ifdef t_a_cmd
     cflag += -DCONFIG_T_A_CMD='"$(t_a_cmd)"'
endif
ifdef t_b_cmd
     cflag += -DCONFIG_T_B_CMD='"$(t_b_cmd)"'
endif
```

2)In submakeA.mk:

```
t_a_cmd = sudo info | grep \"Memory Size:\"
```

3) In submakeB.mk:

```
t_b_cmd = sudo info | grep \"Battery Level:\"
```

4) In the .c file

```
#ifndef CONFIG_T_A_CMD
//do nothing 
#else
     #define T_A_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Memory Size:\""
#endif
#ifndef CONFIG_T_B_CMD
//do nothing 
#else
     #define T_B_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Battery Level:\""
#endif


 #ifdef CONDITION_A
 static const char * funcA(){
   #define SIZE 56
   #ifdef T_A_CMD 
   ...
   ...
 #endif
 }
 #endif 

 #ifdef CONDITION_B
 static const char * funcB(){
   #define SIZE 56
   #ifdef T_B_CMD 
   ...
   ...
 #endif
 }
 #endif
```

When I run it the compiler gives me this error:

```
> Generating info details header file
/bin/sh: 3: syntax error: "(" unexpected
/home/usr/build.mk:59: recipe for target '/home/usr/build/submakeA/A.o' failed
make[1]:***[/home/usr/build/submakeA/A.o] Error2
Makefile:230: recipe for target 'A' failed
make: *** [A] Error
```

I tried to change the location of the `#ifdef T_A_CMD` and `#endif` around but all of the combinations did not help. Could someone let me know what went wrong please? Also, I did not find any documentation or resources about using "DCONFIG" and "CONFIG" in Makefile and how they can be passed all the way to the .c source file. If someone can point me to such resources that will be great too

Comment: What does `make -n …` say when you run the command that gets the shell syntax error?  Messing with single and double quotes on command lines that get passed through multiple levels of shell are, at best, fraught.  Are the lines like `#define T_A_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Memory Size:\"` correct?  There should be an extra double quote at the end, shouldn't there?

Comment: Mostly tangentially, the lines like `static const char *funcB(){` should be `static const char *funcB(void){` so that there's a prototype for the function to check that they're called correctly.  I'm not sure that this 'polymorphic design' is good — but that too is tangential.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you please provide more details as your question is incomplete.  Please note there is nothing special about the word CONFIG in the context of make and C compilers.  Saying `cc -DFOO=BAR myfile.c` simply defines the macro FOO to have the value BAR during the C-preprocessing stage of compiling.

Comment: I just ran the `make -n` and I only see files are getting made for example `make -C AFile make -C BFile make -C CFile` etc. Nothing abnormal or erroneous. Can you let me know what I should look for from the return of `make -n`? Also, unfortunately, I just added the `void` in tu function `funcA()`  and `funcB ()` but the result did not change. But I will keep this tip in mind

Comment: What we want to see is the compile command that make invokes to compile the `.c` file.

Comment: The addition of `void` to give the functions prototypes is wholly tangential to the build problem.  If it had made a difference, it would have been because you had, for example, a call `funcB("abracadabra", "hocus-pocus")'` somewhere which shouldn't be written — and isn't allowed if there's a prototype in scope (but would be allowed if the `void` was omitted).  That's why I said "mostly tangential" — it was never going to be a factor in the build problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear, but it appears that the word `CONFIG` may be unnecessary and causing issues.

I would propose the following `Makefile` content.  I assume `cflag` has a role similar to the more conventional `CFLAGS` in that its value is passed to the C compiler:

```
ifdef t_a_cmd
     cflag += -DT_A_CMD='"$(t_a_cmd)"'
endif
ifdef t_b_cmd
     cflag += -DT_B_CMD='"$(t_b_cmd)"'
endif
```

... and I would propose the following `.c` file content where `T_A_CMD` and `T_B_CMD` are `#define`-d only if they weren't already defined through the `Makefile`.  Change this existing code:

```c
#ifndef CONFIG_T_A_CMD
//do nothing 
#else
     #define T_A_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Memory Size:\""
#endif
#ifndef CONFIG_T_B_CMD
//do nothing 
#else
     #define T_B_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Battery Level:\""
#endif
```

... to this:

```c
#ifndef T_A_CMD
#define T_A_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Memory Size:\""
#endif
#ifndef T_B_CMD
#define T_B_CMD "sudo info | grep \"Battery Level:\""
#endif
```